# In a ring, is a $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$?

Tags: ring-theory, inverse

I vaguely remember seeing this theorem somewhere but am having trouble finding a proof. It is difficult to search for a proof because it is difficult in general for symbolic identities and terms like "inverse", "multiplication", "ring", and "distributive" are quite general in ring theory.

I have gotten this far:

$1=\left(ab\right)^{-1}\left(ab\right)\quad1=bb^{-1}a^{-1}a$

$\left(ab\right)^{-1}\left(ab\right)=bb^{-1}a^{-1}a$

$\left(ab\right)^{-1}\left(ab\right)a^{-1}=bb^{-1}a^{-1}aa^{-1}$

$\left(ab\right)^{-1}\left(ab\right)a^{-1}=bb^{-1}a^{-1}$

$b^{-1}\left(ab\right)^{-1}\left(ab\right)a^{-1}=b^{-1}bb^{-1}a^{-1}$

$b^{-1}\left(ab\right)^{-1}\left(ab\right)a^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Without commutativity, I cannot simply rearrange the $\mathrm{LHS}$ to an expression where I can eliminate $(ab)$.

I may be taking the wrong approach, so any help (including starting over from the beginning) is welcome.

Comment: You only need the *associative* property of multiplication in a ring.

Comment: Alternatively, note that the units of a ring form a group, and hence the fact that the formula is true for groups implies that it's true for rings.

Comment: So perhaps we prove: if $a$ and $b$ are both invertible, then $ab$ is invertible and $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde not a duplicate because OP hasn't proved that the units form a ring.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you can't close a question as a duplicate of two questions just because you can prove it via what is proved in those two questions. If so, you might have to close every question as duplicate of a pathway of questions.

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, I agree with you in principle. However, here I would still think, the main part of the question is just $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ from the group situation. So I still feel it is nothing new.

Comment: I assumed that this had been covered before but that I was just having trouble finding the answer because I wasn't searching the correct terms.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Allow me to expand on my argument. This post asks to prove that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$. You propose to close it as duplicate of two questions, one proving that the units form a group and one proving that the equation holds in a group. Problem is, none of those are duplicates in and of themselves, and even so, you don't even need to prove that the units form a group to prove that the identity holds for the units of the ring.

Comment: @KennyLau As I said, I agree with you in principle. I would nevertheless consider it as a duplicate of the question for groups, even though it is formulated for a ring (but the OP makes clear, that it is exactly the group theory argument, which is missing). But anyway, the question will not be closed, if other people do not agree.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b \in R$ be units with $a',b'$ being their inverses respectively. Let $1$ be the unity of the ring.

We now show that $b'a'$ is the inverse of $ab$, i.e. $(ab)(b'a') = 1 = (b'a')(ab)$.

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
(ab)(b'a') &=& a(b(b'a')) & \text{associativity} \\
&=& a((bb')a') & \text{associativity} \\
&=& a((1)a') & \text{definition of }b' \\
&=& aa' & \text{definition of unity} \\
&=& 1 & \text{definition of }a' \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
(b'a')(ab) &=& b'(a'(ab)) & \text{associativity} \\
&=& b'((a'a)b) & \text{associativity} \\
&=& b'((1)b) & \text{definition of }a' \\
&=& b'b & \text{definition of unity} \\
&=& 1 & \text{definition of }b' \\
\end{array}$$
$\blacksquare$

Comment: Does this assume that the theorem we are trying to prove is true?

Comment: Of course not .

Comment: Why not? You start with $(ab)(b^\prime{a}^\prime)=1$ which is only true if $(ab)^\prime=b^\prime{a}^\prime$.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern read the whole sentence. "We now show that ...".

Comment: Yes, "We show that..." only by assuming  $(ab)(b^\prime{a}^\prime)=1$ which is only true if $(ab)^\prime=b^\prime{a}^\prime$.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern It isn't assuming that $(ab)(b'a')=1$. It's just telling you what we are going to prove.

Comment: Ooops...I see that I kept reading $(ab)$ as $(ab)^\prime$. I apologize for the mistake.